# Не работает пагинация для page/2 страницы архива пользовательской таксономии wordpress(taxonomy.php)

Tags: wordpress, pagination, навигация

В wordpress создал пользовательский тип и пользовательскую таксономию.
В файле архива таксономии taxonomy.php вывел все посты. Далее добавил постраничную навигацию. Которая, если переходить на 2, 3 и т.д.. страницы не работает почему-то - вылетает 404 ошибка, страница не найдена. Структура URL:

http://wp_test.loc/taxnews/allnews/page/2/

taxnews - имя таксономии

allnews - имя общего терма(например общая категория новостей)

В Настройках - Чтение - На страницах блога отображать не более, стоит цифра 3, постов 8 шт.

```
// определение id терма
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
// определение всех данных терма
$term    = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, 'taxnews' );
print_r($term);
// определение количества странц с записями
$paged   = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// получение записей указанного терма в указанной таксономии
$query   = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxnews',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term->slug
        )
    )
) );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    $query->the_post();

    if ( get_post_type() == 'news' ) { the_title(); }
}

// вывод меню навигации
echo paginate_links( array(
    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    'total'     => $query->max_num_pages,
    'post_type' => 'news',
) );

wp_reset_query();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что при регистрации пользовательского типа записи в опции  'exclude_from_search' => 'false' нужно было поставить false, а у меня стояло true.